# ESP32 send data while blinking LED

Tags: esp32

Can I program my ESP32 to send a string MQTT data while also blinking the InBuilt LED?

If yes, then how to do so

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure you can. You can use something like the BlinkWithoutDelay example included in the Arduino IDE so that your program can run (for example sending MQTT data) while the LED is turned on and off with the correct frequency. As long as sending the MQTT data does not take longer than the on- or off period of the LED, this will work.

Comment: Take a look at the [blink-without-delay example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay) to get an idea of how "multitasking" can be implemented. But as @HigorMaiaConcessa mentioned, the ESP supports FreeRTOS where you don't have to care much about how it works.

Comment: My opinion is that using multiple cores for extremely simple tasks such as blinking an LED is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP32 have two core, each core can do diferents tasks. Then, you can send data with one core and blink the LED with another core.

To do this, you need to use a multicore programming. I recommend to use the `FreeRTOS` (ESP32 support this). [See more](https://www.freertos.org/).

Look the example "Let's multitask: Blink with Hello" [here](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Hello_World_with_ESP32_Explained), is that what  you want.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html) about the `FreeRTOS` in ESP32.

Example in Arduino IDE:

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>

// define two tasks for Blink & AnalogRead
void TaskBlink( void *pvParameters );
void TaskAnalogRead( void *pvParameters );

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {

  // Now set up two tasks to run independently.
  xTaskCreate(
    TaskBlink
    ,  (const portCHAR *)"Blink"   // A name just for humans
    ,  128  // Stack size
    ,  NULL
    ,  2  // priority
    ,  NULL );

  xTaskCreate(
    TaskAnalogRead
    ,  (const portCHAR *) "AnalogRead"
    ,  128 // This stack size can be checked & adjusted by reading Highwater
    ,  NULL
    ,  1  // priority
    ,  NULL );

  // Now the task scheduler, which takes over control of scheduling individual tasks, is automatically started.
}

void loop()
{
  // Empty. Things are done in Tasks.
}

/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------- Tasks ---------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

void TaskBlink(void *pvParameters)  // This is a task.
{
  (void) pvParameters;

  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  for (;;) // A Task shall never return or exit.
  {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    vTaskDelay( 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ); // wait for one second
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    vTaskDelay( 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ); // wait for one second
  }
}

void TaskAnalogRead(void *pvParameters)  // This is a task.
{
  (void) pvParameters;
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (;;)
  {
    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    // print out the value you read:
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    vTaskDelay(1);  // one tick delay (15ms) in between reads for stability
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/feilipu/using-freertos-multi-tasking-in-arduino-ebc3cc).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Are there any Arduino IDE Examples available, since it is more understandable in it

Comment: [Look this example](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/feilipu/using-freertos-multi-tasking-in-arduino-ebc3cc). I added the example in the answer.

Comment: While true, it seems like a large increase in complexity for a relatively low gain (and there are multiple task schedulers for Arduino that don't involve an RTOS). It's also my understanding that unless tasks are specifically pinned to a core there's no guarantee regarding multicore-ness.

Comment: So I guess giving same priority to 2 small tasks will make them execute simultaneously. Am I right?

Comment: If run in diferents cores, then will execute simultaneously. If run in the same core with the same priority, will run merging each one.